# How do you parse xmlns:a="wm"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, exchange-server

Does anyone know how to parse this XML using JQuery or Javascript?

I tried using $.parseXML, but I'm not able to get each field.

```
<a:response xmlns:a="WM">
 <a:addresslist>
    <a:item>
      <a:DN>Doe, John </a:DN>
      <a:PH>+1 (111) 212-2381</a:PH>
      <a:OF>345 Ave, Floor 2</a:OF>
      <a:TL>Technical     Specialist</a:TL>
      <a:CP>Businessname</a:CP>
      <a:AN>JDoe</a:AN>
      <a:EM>John.Doe@testemail</a:EM>
    </a:item>
 </a:addresslist>
</a:response>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var data = '<a:response xmlns:a="WM"> <a:addresslist>    <a:item>      <a:DN>Doe, John </a:DN>      <a:PH>+1 (111) 212-2381</a:PH>      <a:OF>345 Ave, Floor 2</a:OF>      <a:TL>Technical     Specialist</a:TL>      <a:CP>Businessname</a:CP>      <a:AN>JDoe</a:AN>      <a:EM>John.Doe@testemail</a:EM>    </a:item> </a:addresslist></a:response>';
    var xml = $($.parseXML(data));
    var nodes = xml.find("a\\:item *");
    $.each(nodes, function(a, b){
        alert($(b).text());
    });
});
```

Example @: http://jsfiddle.net/Cybernate/tf2z2/1/

Comment: That jquery function works properly, but when i change my data source to the url that is pulling that same xml data it does not enter the $.each and alert each item's text. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check if the xml returned by the url is same as what's stated in the example?

Comment: <html><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">&lt;a:response xmlns:a="WM"&gt;&lt;a:addresslist&gt;&lt;a:item&gt;&lt;a:DN&gt;Doe, John&lt;/a:DN&gt;&lt;a:PH&gt;+1 (111) 111-3781&lt;/a:PH&gt;&lt;a:OF&gt;Oak Ave, Floor 2&lt;/a:OF&gt;&lt;a:TL&gt;Technical Specialist&lt;/a:TL&gt;&lt;a:CP&gt;Corporation&lt;/a:CP&gt;&lt;a:AN&gt;JDoe&lt;/a:AN&gt;&lt;a:EM&gt;John.Doe@email&lt;/a:EM&gt;&lt;/a:item&gt;&lt;/a:addresslist&gt;&lt;/a:response&gt;</pre></body></html>

Comment: I'm attempting to build what this person did here except I need to use JQuery not asp/vb, and I'm not sure why the data coming back contains HTML. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2008/06/11/getting-a-list-of-mailboxes.aspx